# How load a form in new aspx page?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, page-layout, list-form

I work in SharePoint Designer 2010. 
I created new aspx page to insert there a form from my list.
I "edit file in advanced mode" and then choose:

"New Item Form" -> "Custom list form" then I choose "My list"and I check "new item form".

When I click OK I didn't get my form but some automatically generated form. What should I do to get my form?

Comment: Do you need to create a custom new form via SP Designer? but you face the issue in showing the form fields!

Comment: I have ready form created in InfoPath. I want this form to be shown in a newly created page.

Comment: Okay, Could you try to edit your page and add InfoPath form web part via browser?

Comment: Yes I can add a form in this way. Is it possible now to remove all menus and ribbon? I need clear page only with form and nothing else

Comment: Ok, adding InfoPath form web part helped me a lot. Thank you @M.Qassas !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to load "my form" in new aspx page, go to site pages in SharePoint Designer 2010. Then I choose my page and:

Edit in advanced mode -> Insert -> Web Part -> InfoPath Form Web Part.

Then double click on new item and there I could choose my form and edit everything.